# Scala (Zeppeline) : Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to get data from Twitter through streaming.
I am getting data in `twt` varibale.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("#hadoop", "#bigdata", "#spark", "#hortonworks", "#HDP"))
//tweets.saveAsObjectFiles("/models/Twitter_files_", ".txt")
 case class Tweet(createdAt:Long, text:String, screenName:String)

val twt = tweets.window(Seconds(60))
//twt.foreach(status => println(status.text())

import sqlContext.implicits._

val temp = twt.map(status=>
  Tweet(status.getCreatedAt().getTime()/1000,status.getText(), status.getUser().getScreenName())
    ).foreachRDD(rdd=>
      rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("tweets")
    )
twt.print

ssc.start()
```

here is the error :

```
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:528)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:528)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:709)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:266)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tweet` class is not `Serializable`, so extend that.

It's a common Spark issue, and the stack tells you exactly what is trying to serialize since Spark 1.3, I believe

Comment: I have added like this : case class Tweet(createdAt:Long, text:String, screenName:String) extends Serializable . Is this correct way of doing that? becoz its giving me the same error.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Can you show more of the stacktrace?

Comment: See how it says "field name: ssc" and above "object not serializable"? I think you're missing some code in your question. Is that your entire Zeppelin cell? Where does ssc come from?

Comment: Do you suggest anything with respect StreamingContext?

Comment: I think the problem is that `twt.print` shouldnt be there. It also isn't the correct way to test your data. Also you're registering a new temp table for each RDD twitter feed, but doing nothing with that table...